# Discord.JS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making discord bot with Discord JS but never used Node JS before so I'm newbee. Almost all code in my bot was written by someone in the internet. I only used it.

At this moment my task is to find out if there is an attachment in the message in order to work with it later.
All bot code is divided into main core and a folder with commands.

Core:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
let config = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const prefix = config.prefix;


  fs.readdir('./cmds', (err, files) => { 
    if (err) console.log(err)

    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js')
    if (jsfile.length <= 0) return console.log('Commands not found!')

    console.log(`Loaded ${jsfile.length} commadns`)
    jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
        let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`)
        client.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
    });
});
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(' ')
  let command = messageArray[0]
  let args = messageArray.slice(1)

  let command_file = client.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length))
  if (command_file) command_file.run(client, message, args, prefix)
})

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(client.user.username + " started!");
});
  client.login(config.token);
```

Module that doesn't work:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require("fs");
let config = require('../config.json');

  module.exports.run = async (client,message,args,prefix) => {
    if (message.attachments != 0)
    {
        console.log( message.attachments.array()[0].url )
    }
    else
    {
        message.channel.send('Attachments not found')
    }
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: "fill"
}
```

But when i write command -fill without picture in message I'm getting error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

Comment: `if (message.attachments != 0)` is flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should properly learn javascript before attempting to make a discord bot. Just trying something so complex at the beginning will only frustrate you and wont help you understand the basics.

To answer your question:

```js
message.attachments.array()[0].url
```

This snippet is getting the first file attachment of the message and then trying to get the URL of it.
If there is no first file attachment (because the message has no attachments) then it can not get the URL of it, thus crashing.

A simple way of fixing this would be checking if there is a first attachment before trying to get the URL of it. Example:

```
if (message.attachments.array()[0] != null) {
  console.log(message.attachments.array()[0].url)
} else {
  console.log("The message has no attachments!")
}
```

Comment: You could also do `let log = message.attachments.array()[0]?.url || 'This message has no attachments'; console.log(log)`